# CALL on files with special symbols fail

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parameter-passing, method-call

I was trying to do some operations to every file in a folder.

```
for %%d in (*.txt) do call:test "%%d"
pause
exit /B

:test
echo %1
```

Usually this works fine, but if there is a file `%~aaa.txt` in the folder, it says that `The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~aaa.txt`.

How to make it handle this correctly? Maybe some unescaping?

Comment: It is possible to work around this problem with `for %%I in (*.txt) do set "FileName=%%I" & call :test` and `echo "%FileName%"` in subroutine `test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `call` command parses the command line `call:test "%%d"` (which should read `call :test "%%~d"`) a second time:

1. At first, `%%d` becomes expanded to the currently iterated file, which is `%~aaa.txt` in the failing situation.
2. The expression `%~aaa.txt` now becomes parsed another time due to the `call` command, where `%~` is the beginning of an [argument reference](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), the following `a` is a modifier (`~a` would expand to file attributes), but there is the decimal digit missing (`%~a1` or `%~aaa2` were valid, for instance).

---

To work around that, you could put the argument into a normal environment variable and read it in the sub-routine (I used [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) therein in order to avoid troubles with special characters):

```cmd
for %%d in (*.txt) do (
    set "ARG=%%~d"
    call :test
)
exit /B

:test
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo(!ARG!
endlocal
exit /B
```

You could also pass the variable name as an argument to the sub-routine:

```cmd
for %%d in (*.txt) do (
    set "ARG=%%~d"
    call :test ARG
)
exit /B

:test
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo(!%~1!
endlocal
exit /B
```

Another way is to let `call` expand the actual file name during its second parsing phase:

```cmd
for %%d in (*.txt) do (
    set "ARG=%%~d"
    call :test "%%ARG%%"
)
exit /B

:test
set "STR=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo(!STR!
endlocal
exit /B
```

To avoid issues with file names containing `^`, `&` or other special characters, a simple `echo(%~1` in the sub-routine is avoided.